# How to save output into 2 files in unix

Tags: unix

Would really appreciate some help with this question.
save lines 3-5 from file called Hello into file called inA and inB. Both inA and inB files will receive the same output from this command, however inB will have its contents preserved.

Comment: Please demonstrate some basic knowledge of the problem space so that responders know where to begin to help you.  What shell are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '3,5p' Hello | tee inA > inB
```